# 'rma.mv' function output- fisher Z or raw correlation

Tags: r, correlation, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis, fisher-transform

I would like to ask a question regarding the output of the rma.mv function.

I had raw correlations which I transformed into Fisher's Z correlations using the 'escalc' function. Then, I performed a multilevel meta-regression with the 'rma.mv' function.

Now I would like to ask: is the "estimate" output that I get (i.e., the summary effect) given in terms of the raw correlation or the fisher Z transformation? I believe that since I entered the fisher-Z correlations, I should get the output in Fisher Z as well, but I would nevertheless like to verify it.

I attach the code and the output for convenience.

Thank you all for your help

- CODE:

D <- escalc(measure="ZCOR", ri=r, ni=N, data=D, vtype="AV")

metRes1 <- rma.mv(yi=yi,
                  V=vi, 
                  random = ~ factor(id) | Paper_num, 
                  data=D)

- OUTPUT:

Model Results:

estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub 
  0.3813  0.0671  5.6818  <.0001  0.2497  0.5128  ***

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check this your self. Make up a small dummy data-set with large in magnitude r values. I suggest about 0.8 to 0.9. Then run rma.mv and check the estimate. If it is greater than 1 then it must be a z.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great idea! For those interested, I checked this and the results are indeed given in terms of Fisher Z (and not correlations).