# rma.mv effect estimate using "zcor"

Tags: r, meta-analysis

This question has been asked before on this thread: ['rma.mv' function output- fisher Z or raw correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439722/rma-mv-function-output-fisher-z-or-raw-correlation), but the only answer didn't answer the question. I’m using correlation coefficients that I’m transforming into Fisher’s z with escalc(..., measure = "ZCOR", …), and then using these coefficients for the the rma.mv() estimation. When using the summary() function, I get the overall effect estimate. However, I’m not sure about the unit of the effect displayed (under “estimate”). Is this  in raw correlation units or Fisher’s z? I believe that if I use “ZCOR”, rather than “COR”, it’s Fisher’s z, but I can’t find that information anywhere on the documentation.

Comment: Found the answer here and some more: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-December/413916.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['rma.mv' function output- fisher Z or raw correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439722/rma-mv-function-output-fisher-z-or-raw-correlation)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP seems to have answered the question in a comment